# Repaint function messes up the whole frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paint

I have a problem when trying to draw some elements using paint method in Swing.
As title says, my whole frame collapses and does some weird repeating.

I made a separate JPanel so I can manipulate drawn shapes:

```
public class PanelPovrsina extends JPanel{

private ArrayList<Oblik> listaOblika;

public PanelPovrsina() {    
    // svi oblici
    this.listaOblika = new ArrayList<Oblik>();
    this.listaOblika.add(new Kvadrat(new Tacka(50, 50), 50, "zuta", "crvena"));
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if(this.listaOblika.isEmpty()) return; 
    Iterator<Oblik> it = this.listaOblika.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        it.next().crtajUBoji(g);
    }
    repaint(); // this causes problems!
}

public ArrayList<Oblik> getListaOblika() {
    return this.listaOblika;
}

}
```

Here is the frame with this code:

[image]

And here it is without repaint method:

[image]

No, I know repaint method is essential in order to dynamically add shapes and actually draw, but I can't make this work correctly.

Also, as you can see from the code above, background of panel is set to white, but my frame would'n render it.

Hope there is enough information to solve my problem, if not, I will add code of my JFrame!

Thank you!

Comment: Firstly, you should never override the `paint` method.  You should override `paintComponent` instead.  Secondly, as you have discovered, `repaint()` should never be called in the `paint` method (or any method it calls).

Comment: Thanks, using `paintComponent` solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never override the `paint` method, as it handles a number of other things behind the scenes.  You should override `paintComponent` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As @[Joe C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6815131/joe-c) answered, I should have been using paintComponent method, not paint! Working code:

```
public class PanelPovrsina extends JPanel{

private ArrayList<Oblik> listaOblika;

public PanelPovrsina() {
    // svi oblici
    this.listaOblika = new ArrayList<Oblik>();
    this.listaOblika.add(new Kvadrat(new Tacka(50, 50), 50, "zuta", "crvena"));
    this.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    this.setVisible(true);
}


@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (Oblik obl : this.listaOblika) {
        obl.crtajUBoji(g);
    }

    repaint();
}

public ArrayList<Oblik> getListaOblika() {
    return this.listaOblika;
}

}
```